# Recursive function that depends on (k-1) previous terms

Tags: python

I have the following function

`b_k(x) = \sum\limits_{j=0}^{k-1}{a_{k-1-j}(x)b_j(x)}`

I want to know how to efficiently implement the function in python. I know that the kth term depends on (k-1) previous terms where the term b_0(x) = 1. If this depends on 2 or 3 previous terms, I can implement it but since k here is variable, I'm having difficulties to implement it.

Thanks.

Comment: When you say "recurrent", do you mean "recursive"?

Comment: @byxor: you're right, I will edit that.

Comment: I suggest holding the previous terms in a list.  You are clearly going to have to evaluate all the terms b_0(x) to b_k(x), so calculate them iteratively .

Comment: It seems that your current line has a specific syntax. Could you add in a tag with that language ?

Comment: When you say previous terms, are the terms previous data elements (i.e. rolling window of data) or previous output of the function?

Comment: @DarrylG: they are the previous output of the function.

Comment: @MartinBonner: the thing is that each term depends on the previous terms, and currently the way I see things is computationally expensive especially as k becomes big.

Comment: Is it possible to [Memoize the function](https://medium.com/@nkhaja/memoization-and-decorators-with-python-32f607439f84), whereby the previous terms are cached using a decorator?

Comment: @DarrylG: thanks for the link. I don't have an idea on decorator but I will try to read about it.

Comment: @MartinBonner: I was thinking of that but I can't see how one could possibly do that in an efficient way as I may take big values of k.

Comment: @Gloweye: That's TeX.  Tag would not really be appropriate.

Comment: Yes, it would be appropriate. Nobody can answer this question without a basic understanding of TeX. Even if it's just a typesetting. Because the way it looks, I can't for the life of me figure out what that function does right now. Perhaps I would be able to when rendered, but NOT when in code like this.

Comment: Can you formulate that TeX expression in terms of python-like pseudo-code please.  I can't see what the value is.

Comment: @Gloweye That just makes it a bad question.  This is *not* a question about TeX.

Comment: @DarrylG I think an iterative approach, calculating all `b(j,x)` in turn would avoid the need for memozation.

Comment: If we look at this as a filtering problem, where the current output depends upon the previous K outputs (for some finite K), and the filter coefficients {a[0], a[1], ...a[K-1]} depends upon x, then you could use [scipy.signal.lfilter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a recursive function that has a loop in it, to handle recursing a variable number of time. It's probably going to be horribly inefficient, but here's a naive translation of your formula to Python code (with the loop part of a generator expression passed to `sum`):

```
def b(a, k, x):
    return sum(a(k-1-j, x) * b(a, j, x) for j in range(k))
```

That's going to be very slow for large `k` values because you end up repeatedly computing values for the same smaller `k`s over and over.

A much better approach is to use dynamic programming, which lets you build up a list of result values from the bottom up.

```
def b(a, k, x):
    results = []
    for i in range(k+1):
        results.append(sum(a(i-1-j, x) * v for j, v in enumerate(results)))
    return results[k] # return the last value
```

Comment: Thanks @Blckknght, I need to incorporate the information that the first term is equal to 1. So, results initially should be `results = [1]` and the for loop should be rather  `for i in range(1,k+1)`.